# App crashes when trying to open raw using FolioReader

Tags: android, kotlin, text-to-speech, epub, google-text-to-speech

I try to use FolioReader like this in MainActivity:

```
val folioReader:FolioReader = FolioReader.get()
    folioReader.openBook(R.raw.book)
```

but I got this errors... how can I fix this errors?
how can initialze FolioReader Object without error?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$OnUtteranceCompletedListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.folioreader.mediaoverlay.MediaController$2.onInit(MediaController.java:112)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.dispatchOnInit(TextToSpeech.java:824)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:802)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:733)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:712)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:696)
    at com.folioreader.mediaoverlay.MediaController.setTextToSpeech(MediaController.java:104)
    at com.folioreader.ui.fragment.FolioPageFragment.onCreateView(FolioPageFragment.kt:161)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1971)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:311)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:274)
    at com.folioreader.ui.view.DirectionalViewpager.populate(DirectionalViewpager.java:1307)
    at com.folioreader.ui.view.DirectionalViewpager.populate(DirectionalViewpager.java:1085)
    at com.folioreader.ui.view.DirectionalViewpager.onMeasure(DirectionalViewpager.java:1808)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19858)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:632)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:453)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solveVerticalMatchConstraint(Direct.java:750)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:505)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solvingPass(Direct.java:224)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:693)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem(BasicMeasure.java:160)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:291)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
    at
```

thanks for help.